# How can I convert seconds into (Hour:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds) time?

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert seconds into (Hour:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds) time?

Let's say I have 80 seconds; are there any specialized classes/techniques in .NET that would allow me to convert those 80 seconds into (00h:00m:00s:00ms) format like `Convert.ToDateTime` or something?

Answer (score 686, accepted):

For **.Net <= 4.0** Use the TimeSpan class.

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( secs );

string answer = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms", 
                t.Hours, 
                t.Minutes, 
                t.Seconds, 
                t.Milliseconds);
```

(As noted by Inder Kumar Rathore) For **.NET > 4.0** you can use

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

//here backslash is must to tell that colon is
//not the part of format, it just a character that we want in output
string str = time .ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff");
```

(From Nick Molyneux) Ensure that seconds is less than `TimeSpan.MaxValue.TotalSeconds` to avoid an exception.

Comment: `using System;` The class resides in `System.TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 99):

For **.NET > 4.0** you can use

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

//here backslash is must to tell that colon is
//not the part of format, it just a character that we want in output
string str = time .ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff");
```

or if you want date time format then you can also do this

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(time);
string displayTime = dateTime.ToString("hh:mm:tt");
```

For more you can check [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

Comment: You do not need TimeSpan to add seconds to DateTime. Just use DateTime.AddSeconds().

Comment: @MehdiDehghani for 24hr format you've to use 'HH' instead of 'hh'

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I was talking about your first solution, `HH` is invalid there.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani could you please what's wrong in that because it's been 3yrs I've not coded in `.NET/C#`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore `.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff");` is already in `24hr` format. `HH` is not valid there with such input (_the error is `Input string was not in a correct format.`_)

Comment: The constructor to TimeSpan expects number of ticks as parameter. To concert seconds to number of ticks has to to the following: Time =  new TimeSpan(seconds * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond).

Comment: Typo on your code, string displayTime = date.ToString("hh:mm:tt"); [date] should be [dateTime]

Answer (score 28):

If you know you have a number of seconds, you can create a TimeSpan value by calling TimeSpan.FromSeconds:

```
 TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80);
```

You can then obtain the number of days, hours, minutes, or seconds.  Or use one of the ToString overloads to output it in whatever manner you like.

Answer (score 25):

I did some benchmarks to see what's the fastest way and these are my results and conclusions. I ran each method 10M times and added a comment with the average time per run.

If your input milliseconds **are not limited to one day** (your result may be 143:59:59.999), these are the options, from faster to slower:

```
// 0.86 ms
static string Method1(int millisecs)
{
    int hours = millisecs / 3600000;
    int mins = (millisecs % 3600000) / 60000;
    // Make sure you use the appropriate decimal separator
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}.{3:D3}", hours, mins, millisecs % 60000 / 1000, millisecs % 1000);
}

// 0.89 ms
static string Method2(int millisecs)
{
    double s = millisecs % 60000 / 1000.0;
    millisecs /= 60000;
    int mins = millisecs % 60;
    int hours = millisecs / 60;
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:00.000}", hours, mins, s);
}

// 0.95 ms
static string Method3(int millisecs)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecs);
    // Make sure you use the appropriate decimal separator
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}.{3:D3}",
        (int)t.TotalHours,
        t.Minutes,
        t.Seconds,
        t.Milliseconds);
}
```

If your input milliseconds **are limited to one day** (your result will never be greater then 23:59:59.999), these are the options, from faster to slower:

```
// 0.58 ms
static string Method5(int millisecs)
{
    // Fastest way to create a DateTime at midnight
    // Make sure you use the appropriate decimal separator
    return DateTime.FromBinary(599266080000000000).AddMilliseconds(millisecs).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
}

// 0.59 ms
static string Method4(int millisecs)
{
    // Make sure you use the appropriate decimal separator
    return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecs).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");
}

// 0.93 ms
static string Method6(int millisecs)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecs);
    // Make sure you use the appropriate decimal separator
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}.{3:D3}",
        t.Hours,
        t.Minutes,
        t.Seconds,
        t.Milliseconds);
}
```

In case your input is **just seconds**, the methods are slightly faster. Again, if your input seconds **are not limited to one day** (your result may be 143:59:59):

```
// 0.63 ms
static string Method1(int secs)
{
    int hours = secs / 3600;
    int mins = (secs % 3600) / 60;
    secs = secs % 60;
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", hours, mins, secs);
}

// 0.64 ms
static string Method2(int secs)
{
    int s = secs % 60;
    secs /= 60;
    int mins = secs % 60;
    int hours = secs / 60;
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", hours, mins, s);
}

// 0.70 ms
static string Method3(int secs)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs);
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
        (int)t.TotalHours,
        t.Minutes,
        t.Seconds);
}
```

And if your input seconds **are limited to one day** (your result will never be greater then 23:59:59):

```
// 0.33 ms
static string Method5(int secs)
{
    // Fastest way to create a DateTime at midnight
    return DateTime.FromBinary(599266080000000000).AddSeconds(secs).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}

// 0.34 ms
static string Method4(int secs)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}

// 0.70 ms
static string Method6(int secs)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs);
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
        t.Hours,
        t.Minutes,
        t.Seconds);
}
```

As a final comment, let me add that I noticed that `string.Format` is a bit faster if you use `D2` instead of `00`.

Answer (score 11):

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx

Answer (score 10):

The TimeSpan constructor allows you to pass in seconds. Simply declare a variable of type TimeSpan amount of seconds. Ex:

```
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 500);
span.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

In VB.NET, but it's the same in C#:

```vb
Dim x As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 80)
debug.print(x.ToString())
' Will print 00:01:20
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you use the `TimeSpan` class for this.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80);
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());

    t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(868693412);
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
}
```

Outputs:

```
00:01:20
10054.07:43:32
```

Answer (score 4):

For **.NET < 4.0** (e.x: **Unity**) you can write an extension method to have the `TimeSpan.ToString(string format)` behavior like **.NET > 4.0**

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
    public static string ToString(this TimeSpan time, string format)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today.Add(time);
        return dateTime.ToString(format);
    }
}
```

And from anywhere in your code you can use it like:

```
var time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeElapsed);

string formattedDate = time.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff");
```

This way you can format any `TimeSpan`object by simply calling ToString from anywhere of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why do people need TimeSpan **AND** DateTime if we have DateTime.AddSeconds()?

```
var dt = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1).AddSeconds(totalSeconds);
```

The date is arbitrary.
totalSeconds can be greater than 59 and it is a double.
Then you can format your time as you want using DateTime.ToString():

```
dt.ToString("H:mm:ss");
```

This does not work if totalSeconds < 0 or > 59:

```
new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, totalSeconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

to get total seconds

```
var i = TimeSpan.FromTicks(startDate.Ticks).TotalSeconds;
```

and to get datetime from seconds

```
var thatDateTime = new DateTime().AddSeconds(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return in hh:mm:ss format

```
 public static string ConvertTime(long secs)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs);
        string displayTime = $"{ts.Hours}:{ts.Minutes}:{ts.Seconds}";
        return displayTime;
    }
```

Comment: You must not have tested this.  `ConvertTime(80)` returns `0:1:20` and `ConvertTime(61)` returns `0:1:1`, both of which are `h:m:s`.  Using string interpolation also results in longer code than `ToString()`, as used in other answers, and also makes it harder to visualize the formatted string length.

Answer (score 0):

```
 TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(EnergyRestoreTimer.Instance.SecondsForRestore);
            string sTime = EnergyRestoreTimer.Instance.SecondsForRestore < 3600
                ? $"{t.Hours:D2}:{t.Minutes:D2}:{t.Seconds:D2}"
                : $"{t.Minutes:D2}:{t.Seconds:D2}";
            time.text = sTime;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private string ConvertTime(double miliSeconds)
{
    var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(totalMiliSeconds);
    // Converts the total miliseconds to the human readable time format
    return timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff");
}
```

//Test

```
    [TestCase(1002, "00:00:01:002")]
    [TestCase(700011, "00:11:40:011")]
    [TestCase(113879834, "07:37:59:834")]
    public void ConvertTime_ResturnsCorrectString(double totalMiliSeconds, string expectedMessage)
    {
        // Arrange
        var obj = new Class();;

        // Act
        var resultMessage = obj.ConvertTime(totalMiliSeconds);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedMessage, resultMessage);
    }
```

Comment: 1. OP asked for conversion from seconds, not milliseconds. 2. How is your answer etter than the currently accepted answer?