# Convert milliseconds to human readable time lapse

Tags: c#, .net, format, timespan

I would like to format some commands execution times in a human readable format, for example:

```
3 -> 3ms
1100 -> 1s 100ms
62000 -> 1m 2s
etc ..
```

Taking into account days, hours, minutes, seconds, ...

Is it possible using `C#`?

Comment: Basically you just have to use modulo and division.

Comment: how about `new TimeSpan(30000).ToString()`?

Comment: Well, I'm asking because I have other things to do here, in my company, better than basic programming exercises ;-)

Comment: @DanielPeñalba: then, instead of asking whether it's possible using C# (yes, it is), you should have asked "is there a ready-made class which does this?"

Comment: So you're basically asking for a `TimeSpan.Format` custom string that doesn't result in "0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 0 min 1 sec 100 ms"?

Comment: If you have 'long milliseconds' then a quick way is 'milliseconds.ToString("n0")' -- this inserts commas as thousands separators, making it easy to see where the seconds are. Not the *most* human readable, but handy if you're in a hurry or don't want to bother creating a TimeSpan.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use TimeSpan class, something like this:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
string answer = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms", 
                        t.Hours, 
                        t.Minutes, 
                        t.Seconds, 
                        t.Milliseconds);
```

It's quite similar as this thread I've just found:

[What is the best way to convert seconds into (Hour:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds) time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463642/c-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-seconds-into-hourminutessecondsmilliseco)

Comment: This would produce `00h:00m:00s:003ms` instead of `3ms` for the input `3`, so I don't think it's exactly what the OP wants ;)

Comment: @Nuffin, he can always alter the code to suit his needs ;) I've just provided an example...

Answer (score 31):

I know this is old, but I wanted to answer with a great nuget package.

```
Install-Package Humanizer
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer

https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer

Example from their readme.md

```
TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1299630020).Humanize(4) => "2 weeks, 1 day, 1 hour, 30 seconds"
```

Answer (score 18):

What about this?

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(86300000 /*whatever */);
var parts = string
                .Format("{0:D2}d:{1:D2}h:{2:D2}m:{3:D2}s:{4:D3}ms",
                    ts.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds)
                .Split(':')
                .SkipWhile(s => Regex.Match(s, @"00\w").Success) // skip zero-valued components
                .ToArray();
var result = string.Join(" ", parts); // combine the result

Console.WriteLine(result);            // prints '23h 58m 20s 000ms'
```

Comment: Nice code but it fails for 100 ms as input. The fix is to use `@"^00\w"` as the Regex.

Answer (score 17):

You could utilize the static `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` method as well as the resulting `TimeSpan`'s `Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Seconds` and `Milliseconds` properties.

But I'm busy right now, so I'll leave the rest to you as an exercise.

Answer (score 9):

.NET 4 accepts format in `TimeSpan.Tostring()`.

For other you can implement extension method like

```
    public static string Format(this TimeSpan obj)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (obj.Hours != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(obj.Hours);
            sb.Append(" "); 
            sb.Append("hours");
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
        if (obj.Minutes != 0 || sb.Length != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(obj.Minutes);
            sb.Append(" "); 
            sb.Append("minutes");
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
        if (obj.Seconds != 0 || sb.Length != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(obj.Seconds);
            sb.Append(" "); 
            sb.Append("seconds");
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
        if (obj.Milliseconds != 0 || sb.Length != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(obj.Milliseconds);
            sb.Append(" "); 
            sb.Append("Milliseconds");
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
        if (sb.Length == 0)
        {
            sb.Append(0);
            sb.Append(" "); 
            sb.Append("Milliseconds");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

and call as

```
foreach (TimeSpan span in spans)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}",  span.Format()));
}
```

Comment: I've used this approach and I just wanted to note that the highest interval (in this case `obj.Hours`) should be `obj.TotalHours,ToString("0")`. `.TotalHours` so it can show values above 24h, and `,ToString("0")` to convert it to a single digit instead of a comma separated value.

Answer (score 8):

```
public static string ReadableTime(int milliseconds)
{
    var parts = new List<string>();
    Action<int, string> add = (val, unit) => { if (val > 0) parts.Add(val+unit); };
    var t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);

    add(t.Days, "d");
    add(t.Hours, "h");
    add(t.Minutes, "m");
    add(t.Seconds, "s");
    add(t.Milliseconds, "ms");

    return string.Join(" ", parts);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach for longer time spans (for which `t.TotalDays` also works).

Comment: Great approach, and for optional formatting. 

Action<int, string, int> add = (val, unit, zeroplaceholder) => {if (val > 0) parts.Add( string.Format( "{0:DZ}X".Replace("X", unit.ToString()) .Replace("Z",zeroplaceholder.ToString()) , val ); }; 
and call with 
add(t.Milliseconds, "ms", 4); to get  2m 37s 0456ms

Answer (score 6):

Old question, new answer:

```
public static string GetReadableTimeByMs(long ms)
{
   TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
   if (t.Hours > 0) return $"{t.Hours}h:{t.Minutes}m:{t.Seconds}s";
   else if (t.Minutes > 0) return $"{t.Minutes}m:{t.Seconds}s";
   else if (t.Seconds > 0) return $"{t.Seconds}s:{t.Milliseconds}ms";
   else return $"{t.Milliseconds}ms";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This probably has a slightly different output than requested, but the result is human readable - and it can be adapted to fit many other use cases.

```
private static List<double> _intervals = new List<double>
{
    1.0 / 1000 / 1000,
    1.0 / 1000,
    1,
    1000,
    60 * 1000,
    60 * 60 * 1000
};
private static List<string> _units = new List<string>
{
    "ns",
    "µs",
    "ms",
    "s",
    "min",
    "h"
};

public string FormatUnits(double milliseconds, string format = "#.#")
{
    var interval = _intervals.Last(i=>i<=milliseconds);
    var index = _intervals.IndexOf(interval);

    return string.Concat((milliseconds / interval).ToString(format) , " " , _units[index]);
}
```

Example calls...

```
Console.WriteLine(FormatUnits(1));
Console.WriteLine(FormatUnits(20));
Console.WriteLine(FormatUnits(300));
Console.WriteLine(FormatUnits(4000));
Console.WriteLine(FormatUnits(50000));
Console.WriteLine(FormatUnits(600000));
Console.WriteLine(FormatUnits(7000000));
Console.WriteLine(FormatUnits(80000000));
```

...and results:

```
1000 µs
20 ms
300 ms
4 s
50 s
10 min
1.9 h
22.2 h
```

Answer (score 2):

For example to get `00:01:35.0090000` as 0 hours, 1 minutes, 35 seconds and 9 milliseconds you can use this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed:" +TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(numberOfMilliseconds).ToString());
```

Your output:

```
Time elapsed: 00:01:35.0090000
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("%d 'd' %h 'h' %m 'm' %s 'seconds' %ms 'ms'")
```

Comment: The question is about `TimeSpan`s, not `DateTime`s. With a `DateTime`, you'll always end up with at least one day, which wouldn't really match the input of 3 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` function

```
var tspan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(YOUR_MILLI_SECONDS);
int h = tspan.Hours;
int m = tspan.Minutes;
int s = tspan.Seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i normally hate writing if statements but some times what you really have is a nail and need a hammer.

```
string time;
if (elapsedTime.TotalMinutes > 2)
    time = string.Format("{0:n2} minutes", elapsedTime.TotalMinutes);
else if (elapsedTime.TotalSeconds > 15)
    time = string.Format("{0:n2} seconds", elapsedTime.TotalSeconds);
else
    time = string.Format("{0:n0}ms", elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds);
```