# Convert integer to timespan

Tags: c#

How can I convert an `int` to `TimeSpan`?

example `486000000000` is `int` as number of ticks. I want it to be represented as `TimeSpan`

Comment: What does the integer represent? Seconds, minutes, days or something else?

Comment: Does it represent minutes, ticks, seconds, milliseconds, what? Also what have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463642/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-seconds-into-hourminutessecondsmilliseconds

Comment: It represent Ticks.. I figured it out thanks a lot guys

Comment: I added a comment to say what that big value "int" is.

Answer (score 71):

You can use the From methods, those will allow you to convert days/hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds/ticks to TimeSpam format as follows:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(486000000000);
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
```

You can replace `FromTicks` with

- [FromDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromdays.aspx)
- [FromHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx)
- [FromMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.frommilliseconds.aspx)
- [FromMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx)
- [FromSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx)
- [FromTicks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromticks.aspx)