# How convert TimeSpan to 24 hours and minutes String?

Tags: c#, tostring, timespan

I use this code for converting `Timespan` to `String` (for ex: 14:53) :

```
myTimeSpan.ToString("hh:mm");
```

but this error occurs:

> Input string was not in a correct format

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463642/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-seconds-into-hourminutessecondsmilliseconds

Comment: @AbhishekShetty; yes, however, the answers are pre .NET 4 (without `TimeSpan.ToString`).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
myTimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm")
```

[**Custom TimeSpan Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee372287.aspx)

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder
>   separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours,
>   hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these
>   symbols must be included in the custom format string as string
>   literals. For example, "dd.hh\:mm" defines a period (.) as the
>   separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator
>   between hours and minutes.

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't handle periods of greater than 24 hours (it loses the days part).

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Correct. I assumed OP's maximum is 24hours because of the title and what he has tried. He could include the days: `myTimeSpan.ToString(@"d\.hh\:mm")`

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `@"hh\:mm\"` for `TimeSpan`. Timespan formatting is not exactly same as `DateTime`

```
myTimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

Check out [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 12):

```
var result = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}",  myTimeSpan.Hours, myTimeSpan.Minutes);
```

Comment: This retains + and - in offset for time zone which is important. 
i.e. `15.10.2014 14:00:00 +02:00` representing 2pm local time in a timezone of +2 UTC.

Answer (score 4):

From [`TimeSpan.ToString Method (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx)

```
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(14, 53, 0);
Console.WriteLine(t.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
```

As an alternative you can use `String.Format` like;

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}:{1}", t.Hours, t.Minutes));
```

- [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx)
- [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

*Remember*, `TimeSpan.ToString(String)` overload only avaiable for .NET 4 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work 100% !!

```
myTimeSpan.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm");.
```