# How to convert string to datetime in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to count total time in `hh:mm:ss` format. and I have minutes in `int` like (465).

I made:

```
CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, cast(cast(TotalMin/60 as int) as nvarchar(50)) + ' : ' + cast(TotalMin%60 as nvarchar(50))),108) AS TotalMin
```

but it shows below error. Not in SQL Server but when I run code in c#:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: Show us your C# code to run this query and get the results from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to get the string in SQL Server. It will convert hours and minutes and add `00` for seconds as you don't have them (you're using integer value for minutes):

```
declare @min int = 465

select right('0' + cast(@min/60 as varchar(2)),2)
    + ':'
    + right('0' + cast((@min - (@min/60)*60) as varchar(2)),2)
    + ':00'
```

It will work for up to 5999 minutes (99 hours and 59 minutes).

---

If you need a Unicode version:

```
declare @min int = 465

select right(N'0' + cast(@min/60 as nvarchar(2)),2)
    + N':'
    + right(N'0' + cast((@min - (@min/60)*60) as nvarchar(2)),2)
    + N':00'
```

Comment: Your code working but it shows "@" in place of ":" exa: 00@56@00

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMinutes( TotalMin);
```

and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463642/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-seconds-into-hourminutessecondsmilliseconds) for more

Comment: I can not change Data type because I'm getting converting records from excel file.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyDate = CONVERT(datetime, '2009/07/16 08:28:01', 120)
```

For a full discussion of CAST and CONVERT, including the different date formatting options, see the MSDN Library Link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will help you
You want to multiply out to milliseconds as the fractional part is discarded.

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 121.25 * 1000, 0)
```

If you want it without the date portion you can use CONVERT, with style 114

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ms, 121.25 * 1000, 0), 114)
```