# Coding for splitting the minutes into day-hr-min

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a time expressed in minutes and I want to format it as `day-hr-min` with two digits for each part.

For example:

```
2305 minutes  =>  01-14-25
2602 minutes  =>  01-19-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a near-duplicate of [What is the best way to convert seconds into (Hour:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds) time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/463642/10263)

In your case you would do:

```
string formatted = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2602).ToString(@"dd\-hh\-mm");
```

Result:

```
01-19-22
```

Comment: Thanks.Let my try and I will get back to you.