# Plotting 2D heat map

Tags: c#, charts, heatmap

I have a chart on which I want to plot a heat map; the only data I have is humidity and temperature,  which represent a point in the chart.

How do I get the rectangular type of heat map on the chart in c#?

What I want is similar to picture below :

[image]

What I really want is a rectangular region in the chart which is plotted in different color based on the point that i get from the list of points and form the colorful section in the chart.

Comment: The problem is, that you don't know what your problem is. Do you have code? Why isn't it working? Please read the [faq] and [ask].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a choice of at least three ways to create a chart with colored rectangles that make up a heat map.

Here is one  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461579/displaying-heatmap-in-datagridview-from-listlistt-in-c-sharp/26482670?s=3|1.8616#26482670)
that uses/abuses a `DataGridView`. While I would not suggest this, the post contains a useful function that creates nice color lists to use in your task.

Then there is the option to draw the chart using GDI+ methods, namely `Graphics.FillRectangle`.  This not hard at all but once you want to get those nice extras a Chart control offers, like scaling, axes, tooltips etc the work adds up.. See below!

So let's have a look at option three: Using the `Chart` control from the `DataVisualization` namespace.

Let's first assume that you have created a list of colors:

```
List<Color> colorList = new List<Color>();
```

And that you have managed to project your data onto a 2D array of int indices that point into the color list:

```
int[,] coloredData = null;
```

Next you have to pick a `ChartType` for your `Series S1` There really is only one I can think of that will help:

```
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
```

Points are displayed by `Markers`. We want the `DataPoints` not really displayed as one of the standard [MarkerTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx).

`Square` would be ok, if we wanted to display squares; but for rectangles it will not work well: Even if we let them overlap there will still be points at the borders that have a different size because they don't fully overlap..

So we use a **custom** marker by setting the `MarkerImage` of each point to a **bitmap** of a suitable size and color.

Here is a loop that adds the `DataPoints` to our `Series` and sets each to have a `MarkerImage`:

```
for (int x = 1; x < coloredData.GetLength(0); x++)
    for (int y = 1; y < coloredData.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        int pt = S1.Points.AddXY(x, y);
        S1.Points[pt].MarkerImage = "NI" +  coloredData[x,y];

    }
```

This takes some explaining: To set a `MarkerImage` that is not at a path on the disk, it has to reside in the `Chart's Images` collection. This means is needs to be of type `NamedImage`. Any image will do, but it has to have a unique name string added to identify it in the `NamedImagesCollection` . I chose the names to be 'NI1', 'NI2'..

Obviously we need to create all those images; here is a function to do that:

```
void createMarkers(Chart chart, int count)
{
    // rough calculation:
    int sw = chart.ClientSize.Width / coloredData.GetLength(0);
    int sh = chart.ClientSize.Height / coloredData.GetLength(1);

    // clean up previous images:
    foreach(NamedImage ni in chart1.Images) ni.Dispose();
    chart.Images.Clear();

    // now create count images:
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sw, sh);
        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            G.Clear(colorList[i]);
        chart.Images.Add(new NamedImage("NI" + i, bmp));
    }
}
```

We want all markers to have at least roughly the right size; so whenever that size changes we set it again:

```
void setMarkerSize(Chart chart)
{
    int sx = chart1.ClientSize.Width / coloredData.GetLength(0);
    int sy = chart1.ClientSize.Height / coloredData.GetLength(1);
    chart1.Series["S1"].MarkerSize = (int)Math.Max(sx, sy);
}
```

This doesn't care much about details like the `InnerPlotPosition`, i.e. the actual area to draw to; so here is some room for refinement..!

We call this when we set up the chart but also upon **resizing**:

```
private void chart1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setMarkerSize(chart1);
    createMarkers(chart1, 100);
}
```

Let's have a look at the result using some cheap testdata:

[image][image]

As you can see resizing works ok..

Here is the full code that set up my example:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Color> stopColors = new List<Color>()
    { Color.Blue, Color.Cyan, Color.YellowGreen, Color.Orange, Color.Red };
    colorList = interpolateColors(stopColors, 100);

    coloredData = getCData(32, 24);
    // basic setup..
    chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("CA");
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    Series S1 = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
    chart1.Legends.Clear();
    // we choose a charttype that lets us add points freely:
    S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;

    Size sz = chart1.ClientSize;

    // we need to make the markers large enough to fill the area completely:
    setMarkerSize(chart1);
    createMarkers(chart1, 100);

    // now we fill in the datapoints
    for (int x = 1; x < coloredData.GetLength(0); x++)
        for (int y = 1; y < coloredData.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            int pt = S1.Points.AddXY(x, y);
            //  S1.Points[pt].Color = coloredData[x, y];

            S1.Points[pt].MarkerImage = "NI" +  coloredData[x,y];
        }
}
```

A few notes on limitations:

- The point will always sit on top of any gridlines. If you really needs those you will have to draw them on top in one of the the `Paint` events.
- The labels as shown are referring to the integers indices of the data array. If you want to show the original data, one way would be to add `CustomLabels` to the axes.. See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294015/convert-seconds-to-hhhmmss-in-a-chart/36329469?s=1|0.0000#36329469)!

This should give you an idea of what you can do with a `Chart` control; to complete your confusion here is how to draw those rectangles in GDI+ using the same colors and data:

```
Bitmap getChartImg(float[,] data, Size sz, Padding pad) 
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sz.Width , sz.Height);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        float w = 1f * (sz.Width - pad.Left - pad.Right) / coloredData.GetLength(0);
        float h = 1f * (sz.Height - pad.Top - pad.Bottom) / coloredData.GetLength(1);
        for (int x = 0; x < coloredData.GetLength(0); x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < coloredData.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colorList[coloredData[x,y]]))
                    G.FillRectangle(brush, pad.Left + x * w, y * h - pad.Bottom, w, h);
            }

    }
    return bmp;
}
```

The resulting Bitmap looks familiar:

[image]

That was simple; but to add all the extras into the space reserved by the padding will not be so easy..

Comment: Thanks for the answer I graps some of logic out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can manually draw such a heat map to the background of the Chart control.

Here is an example:

First, handle the event [PrePaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.prepaint?view=netframework-4.8.1).

```
chart.PrePaint += ChartPrePaint;
```

The method is then executed for deferent elements of the chart, such as Title, Legend, etc. Use the property [ChartElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartpainteventargs.chartelement?view=netframework-4.8.1) to filter the element of type [ChartArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea?view=netframework-4.8.1).

```
private void ChartPrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    var area = e.ChartElement as ChartArea;
    if (area == null)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Next step is to split the chart area into rectangular segments and fill each segment with its own color depending on the settings.

```
private void ChartPrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    var chart = sender as Chart;
    if (chart == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var width = chart.Width;
    var height = chart.Height;

    var area = e.ChartElement as ChartArea;
    if (area == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    /*
     * In this example we plot the average temperature of each period of a day (Y-axis) for each month (X-axis).
     */
    foreach (var month in Observations)
    {
        for (var period = 0; period < month.Value.Length; period++)
        {
            /* 
             * Firstly, find where each segment begins and ends.
             * In this example we split the X-axis proportionally to the number of months and find the edges of each month.
             */
            var x1 = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(area.Name, area.AxisX.AxisName, month.Key);
            var x2 = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(area.Name, area.AxisX.AxisName, month.Key + 1);

            /*
             * Similarly, split the Y-axis into 4 segments for each period of a day.
             */
            var y1 = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(area.Name, area.AxisY.AxisName, period);
            var y2 = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(area.Name, area.AxisY.AxisName, period + 1);

            /*
             * Convert the relative coordinates to absolute ones.
             */
            var x1abs = (float)(x1 / 100 * width);
            var x2abs = (float)((x2 - x1) / 100 * width);

            var y1abs = (float)(y2 / 100 * height);
            var y2abs = (float)((y1 - y2) / 100 * height);

            /*
             * Finally, pick the color of the segment.
             */
            var temperature = month.Value[period];
            var color = GetColor(temperature);

            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
            {
                /*
                 * Fill the segment with its color.
                 */
                e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x1abs, y1abs, x2abs, y2abs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the full version:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WindowsFormsAppHeatMap
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var chart = new Chart { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            chart.PrePaint += ChartPrePaint;
            Controls.Add(chart);

            var area = new ChartArea();
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

            /* Add data to the chart. */
            var series = new Series() { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point };
            series.MarkerSize = 0;
            foreach (var month in Observations)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < month.Value.Length; i++)
                {
                    var index = series.Points.AddXY(month.Key + 0.5, i + 0.5);
                    series.Points[index].Label = month.Value[i].ToString();
                }
            }
            chart.Series.Add(series);

            /* Custom labels for the X-axis. */
            area.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            area.AxisX.Maximum = 12;
            area.AxisX.Interval = 1;
            var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                var month = ci.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i + 1).Substring(0, 3);
                area.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i, i + 1, month);
            }

            /* Custom labels for the Y-axis. */
            area.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
            area.AxisY.Maximum = 4;
            area.AxisY.Interval = 1;
            area.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(0, 1, "Morning");
            area.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(1, 2, "Afternoon");
            area.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(2, 3, "Evening");
            area.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(3, 4, "Night");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Input data for each month and each period of a day (Morning, Afternoon, Evening, Night).
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Dictionary<int, int[]> Observations = new Dictionary<int, int[]>
        {
            {  0, new [] { -15, -10, -10, -18 } },
            {  1, new [] { -18, -12, -13, -20 } },
            {  2, new [] { -14,  -9,  -8, -15 } },
            {  3, new [] {  -5,  -2,  -4,  -7 } },
            {  4, new [] {  -1,   5,   2,  -2 } },
            {  5, new [] {  14,  22,  20,  13 } },
            {  6, new [] {  18,  30,  24,  19 } },
            {  7, new [] {  17,  28,  22,  17 } },
            {  8 ,new [] {  10,  13,  11,   8 } },
            {  9, new [] {   5,  10,   6,   3 } },
            { 10, new [] {  -2,   3,  -1,  -5 } },
            { 11, new [] {  -7,  -5,  -8, -10 } }
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Colors map that states the color for each temperature range.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Dictionary<int, Color> Colors = new Dictionary<int, Color>
        {
            { -35, Color.FromArgb( 0,   0, 255) },
            { -30, Color.FromArgb(40,  67, 255) },
            { -25, Color.FromArgb(53, 115, 255) },
            { -20, Color.FromArgb(53, 168, 255) },
            { -15, Color.FromArgb(40, 220, 254) },
            { -10, Color.FromArgb(64, 255, 240) },
            { -5, Color.FromArgb(144, 244, 194) },
            {  0, Color.FromArgb(183, 254, 140) },
            {  5, Color.FromArgb(219, 254,  92) },
            { 10, Color.FromArgb(249, 255,  16) },
            { 15, Color.FromArgb(255, 225,   0) },
            { 20, Color.FromArgb(255, 178,   0) },
            { 25, Color.FromArgb(255, 133,   0) },
            { 30, Color.FromArgb(255,  80,   0) },
            { 99, Color.FromArgb(179,   0,   0) }
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the color for the specified temperature.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="temperature">A temperature.</param>
        /// <returns>A color.</returns>
        private Color GetColor(int temperature)
        {
            foreach (var color in Colors)
            {
                if (temperature < color.Key)
                {
                    return color.Value;
                }
            }

            return Color.Transparent;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the colorful segments in the chart area.
        /// </summary>
        private void ChartPrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var chart = sender as Chart;
            if (chart == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var width = chart.Width;
            var height = chart.Height;

            var area = e.ChartElement as ChartArea;
            if (area == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            /*
             * In this example we plot the average temperature of each period of a day (Y-axis) for each month (X-axis).
             */
            foreach (var month in Observations)
            {
                for (var period = 0; period < month.Value.Length; period++)
                {
                    /* 
                     * Firstly, find where each segment begins and ends.
                     * In this example we split the X-axis proportionally to the number of months and find the edges of each month.
                     */
                    var x1 = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(area.Name, area.AxisX.AxisName, month.Key);
                    var x2 = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(area.Name, area.AxisX.AxisName, month.Key + 1);

                    /*
                     * Similarly, split the Y-axis into 4 segments for each period of a day.
                     */
                    var y1 = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(area.Name, area.AxisY.AxisName, period);
                    var y2 = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(area.Name, area.AxisY.AxisName, period + 1);

                    /*
                     * Convert the relative coordinates to absolute ones.
                     */
                    var x1abs = (float)(x1 / 100 * width);
                    var x2abs = (float)((x2 - x1) / 100 * width);

                    var y1abs = (float)(y2 / 100 * height);
                    var y2abs = (float)((y1 - y2) / 100 * height);

                    /*
                     * Finally, pick the color of the segment.
                     */
                    var temperature = month.Value[period];
                    var color = GetColor(temperature);

                    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
                    {
                        /*
                         * Fill the segment with its color.
                         */
                        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x1abs, y1abs, x2abs, y2abs);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```