# Can I draw a MarkerStyle upside down?

Tags: c#, data-visualization

I am using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

and I can create a series with a "triangle" MarkerStyle.

Is there a way to draw it with the point facing down?

I would like to show "up" and "down" type markers

```
public MarkerStyle MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Triangle;
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is to draw your own marker.
Then set `MarkerImage` property to use a custom image for it.

```
MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
MarkerImage = 'Path to the image
```

Comment: Note that instead of a path is is often preferrable to us a `NamedImage`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614148/make-chart-legend-represent-two-colors/36619240?s=2|0.1325#36619240) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796524/charting-rectangles-of-arbitrary-dimensions/36798066?s=5|0.0792#36798066) for  examples