# Highlight data point in chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, charts, highlight

I am building my first own graph and im getting to what i need step by step.
But i have a small problem that i can not figure out. 
My Line Chart shows data and when i hover with my mouse over the data points it shows the value. But there are no real points or circles on the data points in my chart and i can not seem to get them in the chart.

Here is my chart:

[image: My Chart]

As you can see, it is not clear where the datapoints are. Can anybode please help me figure out how to get circles on those points.

Here is my c# code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=SmmsData;Integrated Security=True");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select DrukSensor,DateTime from SysteemSensorInfo2", con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
        Chart1.DataSource = source;
        Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "DateTime";
        Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "DrukSensor";
        Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 3;
        Chart1.DataBind();
    }
```

And here is my html code:

```
          <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" BackSecondaryColor="0, 0, 192" Palette="Pastel" Width="1026px">
        <series>
            <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series0" ToolTip="#VALY">
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **addition** to the normal way of displaying the `DataPoints` for a given `ChartType`, in your case as `Lines`, you often can also ask to display `Markers`:

[image]

```
 Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "DateTime";
 Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "DrukSensor";
 Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 3;
 Chart1.DataBind();

 Chart1.Series[0].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
 Chart1.Series[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
 Chart1.Series[0].MarkerSize = 4;
```

You have a choice of several [`MarkerStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) including custom images; you can even [create custom images dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796524/charting-rectangles-of-arbitrary-dimensions/36798066?s=2|0.2034#36798066).