# How to display milliseconds into “days : hours : minutes : seconds” in Infragistics UltraChart?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, linechart

I'm using Infragistics UltraChart controls for displaying graphs. (Version 19.1)
My line chart graph is as below

[image]

Here Y-axis is noting but milliseconds(turn around time of `Int64` type), I want to display it like "days:hh:mm:ss" format. Is it possible to display Y- axis lables in this format? while X axis is showing list of sample names (Which is of `string` type) The Ultra line chart data binding code is as below

```
    ultraChartTAT.Data.DataSource = dsTAT.Tables["dtTAT"];
    ultraChartTAT.Data.DataBind();
```

Here `ultraChartTAT` is an UltraChart infragistic control and `dsTAT` is a `DataSet`. The `dsTAT.Tables["dtTAT"]` design structure is as below

```
DataTable dtTAT = new DataTable("dtTAT");
dtTAT.Columns.Add("TAT", typeof(string)); 
dtTAT.Columns.Add("Sample1", typeof(Int64));
dtTAT.Columns.Add("Sample2", typeof(Int64));
dtTAT.Columns.Add("Sample3", typeof(Int64));
dtTAT.Columns.Add("Sample4", typeof(Int64));
dtTAT.Columns.Add("Sample5", typeof(Int64));
dtTAT.Columns.Add("Sample6", typeof(Int64));
dtTAT.Columns.Add("Sample7", typeof(Int64));
dtTAT.Columns.Add("Sample8", typeof(Int64));
```

For more reference take a look on this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/36329469/4524485

In case if any other information is required then add it in comment I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Look at the following post that contains example of using UltraChart with the DateTime column type: https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-windows-forms/68587/timespan-on-y-axis

Comment: This information is not enough to fix above problem. Is there any event which will automatically convert these values at the time of binding (like `RowDataBound` in `DataGridView`) or any other way like using any functions / properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format data for the X/Y axis labels the *IRenderLabel* interface can be used.
In example below the ***DateTimeRenderer*** class is using the *IRenderLabel* interface implementation to display Y-axis labels in the DateTime format:

[image]

For additional information see the Infragistics documentation:
http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.1/CLR2.0/html/Chart_Customize_Labels_Using_the_IRenderLabel_Interface.html

**DateTimeRenderer.cs**

```
using Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;

namespace UltraGrid
{
    public class DateTimeRenderer : IRenderLabel
    {
        readonly DataTable source;
        public DateTimeRenderer(DataTable dt)
        {
            source = dt;
        }

        public string ToString(Hashtable context)
        {
            double dataValue = (double)context["DATA_VALUE"];            
            var dt = new DateTime((long)dataValue);
            return dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }
    }

}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UltraGrid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Statistics");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create columns to hold sample data.
            var column1 = new DataColumn("Sample", typeof(string));
            var column2 = new DataColumn("Line1", typeof(Int64));
            var column3 = new DataColumn("Line2", typeof(Int64));
            var column4 = new DataColumn("Line3", typeof(Int64));

            table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { column1, column2, column3, column4 });

            var now = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            var rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Sample" + i.ToString(), now + rnd.Next(999, 3600000)*1000, now + rnd.Next(999, 3600000)*1000, now + rnd.Next(999, 3600000)*1000 });
            }
        }

        private void LineChartStyles_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ultraChart1.Data.DataSource = table;

            ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.ItemFormatString = "<MY_VALUE>";
            ultraChart1.Tooltips.FormatString = "<MY_VALUE>";
            var MyLabelHashTable = new Hashtable { { "MY_VALUE", new DateTimeRenderer(table) } };

            this.ultraChart1.LabelHash = MyLabelHashTable;
            this.ultraChart1.Data.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace UltraGrid
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement1 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement2 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement3 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement4 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement5 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement6 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.LineChartAppearance lineChartAppearance1 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.LineChartAppearance();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.LineAppearance lineAppearance1 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.LineAppearance() { Thickness = 3 };
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement7 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.LineAppearance lineAppearance2 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.LineAppearance() { Thickness = 3 };
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement8 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.LineAppearance lineAppearance3 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.LineAppearance() { Thickness = 3 };
            Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement paintElement9 = new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement();
            this.ultraChart1 = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinChart.UltraChart();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ultraChart1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.ultraChart1.ChartType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.ChartType.LineChart;
            // 
            // ultraChart1
            // 
            resources.ApplyResources(this.ultraChart1, "ultraChart1");
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(248)))), ((int)(((byte)(220)))));
            paintElement1.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.None;
            paintElement1.Fill = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(248)))), ((int)(((byte)(220)))));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.PE = paintElement1;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F);
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Near;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.ItemFormatString = "<ITEM_LABEL>";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.VerticalLeftFacing;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F);
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.FormatString = "";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Near;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.VerticalLeftFacing;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.SeriesLabels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Labels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.LineThickness = 1;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.MajorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.MajorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.MajorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.MajorGridLines.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.MinorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.MinorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.MinorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.MinorGridLines.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F);
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Far;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.ItemFormatString = "<ITEM_LABEL>";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.VerticalLeftFacing;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.SeriesLabels.FormatString = "";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.SeriesLabels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Far;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.SeriesLabels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.VerticalLeftFacing;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.SeriesLabels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.SeriesLabels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Labels.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.MajorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.MajorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.MajorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.MajorGridLines.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.MinorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.MinorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.MinorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.MinorGridLines.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.X2.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Extent = 110;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F);
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Far;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.ItemFormatString = "<DATA_VALUE:00.##>";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.SeriesLabels.FormatString = "";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.SeriesLabels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Far;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.SeriesLabels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.SeriesLabels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.SeriesLabels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Labels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.LineThickness = 1;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.MajorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.MajorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.MajorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.MajorGridLines.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.MinorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.MinorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.MinorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.MinorGridLines.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.TickmarkInterval = 50D;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.TickmarkStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.AxisTickStyle.Smart;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F);
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Near;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.ItemFormatString = "<DATA_VALUE:00.##>";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.SeriesLabels.FormatString = "";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.SeriesLabels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Near;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.SeriesLabels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.SeriesLabels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.SeriesLabels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Labels.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.MajorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.MajorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.MajorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.MajorGridLines.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.MinorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.MinorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.MinorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.MinorGridLines.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Y2.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F);
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Near;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.ItemFormatString = "";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.SeriesLabels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Near;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.SeriesLabels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.SeriesLabels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.SeriesLabels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Labels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.MajorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.MajorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.MajorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.MajorGridLines.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.MinorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.MinorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.MinorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.MinorGridLines.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F);
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Near;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.ItemFormatString = "";
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.SeriesLabels.HorizontalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Near;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.SeriesLabels.Orientation = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.TextOrientation.Horizontal;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.SeriesLabels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.SeriesLabels.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.VerticalAlign = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Labels.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.MajorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.MajorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.MajorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.MajorGridLines.Visible = true;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.MinorGridLines.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(255));
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.MinorGridLines.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.MinorGridLines.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.MinorGridLines.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Axis.Z2.Visible = false;
            this.ultraChart1.Border.CornerRadius = 5;
            this.ultraChart1.ColorModel.AlphaLevel = ((byte)(150));
            this.ultraChart1.ColorModel.ModelStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.ColorModels.CustomLinear;
            paintElement2.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.Gradient;
            paintElement2.Fill = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(108)))), ((int)(((byte)(162)))), ((int)(((byte)(36)))));
            paintElement2.FillGradientStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.GradientStyle.Horizontal;
            paintElement2.FillStopColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(244)))), ((int)(((byte)(17)))));
            paintElement2.Stroke = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            paintElement3.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.Gradient;
            paintElement3.Fill = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(7)))), ((int)(((byte)(108)))), ((int)(((byte)(176)))));
            paintElement3.FillGradientStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.GradientStyle.Horizontal;
            paintElement3.FillStopColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(53)))), ((int)(((byte)(200)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            paintElement3.Stroke = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            paintElement4.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.Gradient;
            paintElement4.Fill = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(215)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(5)))));
            paintElement4.FillGradientStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.GradientStyle.Horizontal;
            paintElement4.FillStopColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(254)))), ((int)(((byte)(117)))), ((int)(((byte)(16)))));
            paintElement4.Stroke = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            paintElement5.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.Gradient;
            paintElement5.Fill = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(230)))), ((int)(((byte)(190)))), ((int)(((byte)(2)))));
            paintElement5.FillGradientStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.GradientStyle.Horizontal;
            paintElement5.FillStopColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(81)))));
            paintElement5.Stroke = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            paintElement6.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.Gradient;
            paintElement6.Fill = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(252)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))), ((int)(((byte)(10)))));
            paintElement6.FillGradientStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.GradientStyle.Horizontal;
            paintElement6.FillStopColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(66)))));
            paintElement6.Stroke = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.ultraChart1.ColorModel.Skin.PEs.AddRange(new Infragistics.UltraChart.Resources.Appearance.PaintElement[] {
            paintElement2,
            paintElement3,
            paintElement4,
            paintElement5,
            paintElement6});
            this.ultraChart1.Data.EmptyStyle.LineStyle.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dash;
            this.ultraChart1.Data.SwapRowsAndColumns = true;
            this.ultraChart1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.ultraChart1.Legend.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 7F);
            this.ultraChart1.Legend.Location = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LegendLocation.Top;
            this.ultraChart1.Legend.Visible = true;
            lineAppearance1.IconAppearance.CharacterFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F);
            paintElement7.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.None;
            lineAppearance1.IconAppearance.PE = paintElement7;
            lineAppearance1.Key = "Monday";
            paintElement8.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.None;
            lineAppearance2.IconAppearance.PE = paintElement8;
            lineAppearance2.Key = "Tuesday";
            lineAppearance2.LineStyle.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dash;
            paintElement9.ElementType = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.PaintElementType.None;
            lineAppearance3.IconAppearance.PE = paintElement9;
            lineAppearance3.Key = "Wednesday";
            lineAppearance3.LineStyle.DrawStyle = Infragistics.UltraChart.Shared.Styles.LineDrawStyle.Dot;
            lineChartAppearance1.LineAppearances.Add(lineAppearance1);
            lineChartAppearance1.LineAppearances.Add(lineAppearance2);
            lineChartAppearance1.LineAppearances.Add(lineAppearance3);
            this.ultraChart1.LineChart = lineChartAppearance1;
            this.ultraChart1.Name = "ultraChart1";
            this.ultraChart1.Tooltips.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F);
            this.ultraChart1.Tooltips.HighlightFillColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
            this.ultraChart1.Tooltips.HighlightOutlineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
            this.Controls.Add(this.ultraChart1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.LineChartStyles_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ultraChart1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

      private Infragistics.Win.UltraWinChart.UltraChart ultraChart1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving your valuable time :), this solution is working as expected.