# how to create 2 minute countdown timer using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

i want to create a 2 minute timer under text box using Asp.net, i wanted the timer to be in a label under the text box, so i wrote this code in the control page after double click in the timer icon:

```
 int seconds = int.Parse(Label1.Text);
        if (seconds > 0)


            Label1.Text = (seconds - 1).ToString("mm:ss");

        else
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
```

And this code in the aspx file:

```
<span "CodeAsk">ألم تتلقى الرمز ؟</span><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" text="2"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="120000"></asp:Timer>
```

but it's not working, what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Question is not asp.net Core related. Seems to me you've selected all tags you could find :-)

Comment: Use front end javascript for this: https://www.google.nl/search?source=hp&ei=5ktCX52CLZK4kwWi3oWwAQ&q=countdown+time+javascript&oq=countdown+times+jav&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yCAgAEBYQChAeMggIABAWEAoQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoCCAA6CAguEMcBEKMCOgsILhDHARCjAhCTAjoCCC46BQguEJMCOgQIABAKOgQIABANOgYIABANEB5Q6w9YojFgrzdoAHAAeAGAAbwBiAGACJIBBDE4LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? If it is solved, please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979/710667), otherwise, please tell me your still existing problems.

Answer (score 1):

> but it's not working, what is the problem with my code?

Timer needs to be used in conjunction with the **UpdatePanel** control. You can trigger the `ontick` event of the timer through the **AsyncPostBackTrigger** method of the updatepanel.

And for *converting the text of the Label into the form of a timer*, you need to use `TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);` to achieve, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/463668/12884742).

```
 <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <span id="CodeAsk">ألم تتلقى الرمز ؟</span><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="2"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text) * 60);
                string str = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                Label1.Text = str;
            }
        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeSpan.Parse(Label1.Text).TotalSeconds - 1);
            string fromTimeString = result.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            Label1.Text = fromTimeString;
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]