# Kendo Format HH:mm:ss. RadHtmlChart

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-grid, radhtmlchart

I want to  format my data on RadHtmlChart to hh:mm:ss format. I have now for example 61 and i want this to be displayed like 00:01:01.
I've tried this sample `#= kendo.format(\'{0:HH:mm:ss}\', value) #` but this just return me a number 61 on chart. How do i parse this?

Comment: I guess you need to convert the actual value to a `DateTime` so that format works (how do you expect it to know that 61 is *61 seconds* when it could be 61 *anything*?)

Comment: You may need of a TimeSpan, from a number of seconds [`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds). If someone as a flag here is a target (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463642/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-seconds-into-hourminutessecondsmilliseconds)