# Convert Second into minutes in MVC not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am calculating the total length of my video and watch video length in seconds.

When I click on the button in my ASP.NET MVC page called in which I passed the data

```
Total Length: 131
Total Watch: 233
```

Here total length means my video "total length" is 233 seconds and "Total watch" means I have watched 131 seconds video.

```
233 Seconds means: 3.53 (Min: Sec)
131 Seconds means: 2.11 (Min: Sec)
```

Now in my database, I have to convert the SECONDS into minutes and then insert the data.

So I have used this code:

```
ViewDuration = Math.Round((myModel.myWatchCount / 60), 2),
VideoLength = Math.Round((myModel.VideoLength / 60), 2),
```

Pass the value `ViewDuration` and `VideoLength` in the database table.

It shows me

```
Video Length : - 3.88
Video Duration: - 2.18
```

What's wrong with the above code? Please suggest?

**Edit Code**
Here is my MVC Controller. How I assign the value to my Class Field.

```
StudentInfo uvi = new StudentInfo()
{
  ViewDuration = Math.Round((myModel.myWatchCount / 60), 2),
  VideoLength = Math.Round((myModel.VideoLength / 60), 2)
}
```

Comment: The result is right. 233/60 = 3.88 and 131/60 = 2.18

Comment: @Qudus Thank you for your reply. I have checked the calculation, how can I exactly convert the SECOND INTO MINUTE. ` 3.88 to 3.53 ` in my application.

Comment: Is it convenient for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802389/1068246

Answer (score 1):

You should get the remainder after dividing the time in seconds by 60 and append it to the minute value like this if you want the seconds count be expressed in a fraction of 60 instead of 100.

```
var time = $"{timeInSeconds / 60}:{timeInSeconds % 60}";
```

For example

```
var time = $"{233/60}:{233 % 60}";
```

Comment: @MuzafferGalata ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: @op tagged and asked in ASP.Net MVC. Sorry if your answer is also in ASP.Net MVC:

Comment: No worries. He could have simply tagged C#, no point in tagging ASP.NET

Comment: This is plain C# code that can (also) be used in MVC

Comment: @Qudus I tried not working as my requirement sir.

Comment: You asked how you would convert seconds after the decimal to minutes, that is what I did. Can you tell me what value you used that this failed, please clarify.